# Programmatically adding buttons from String[]

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-fragments

Im Trying to dynamically add buttons from items in a `String[]`.
My approach is to programmatically add as many buttons as items in the array, and assign each button a text from that array. (I understand how to add buttons programmatically from the items).

My problem is not being able to pass the `String[] buttonStrings` from class `TestOne` to the fragment `FragmentTest`.

The log returns null for `String[] buttonStrings`, however it returns the correct value for `String title`.

My guess is I'm not initializing `String[] buttonStrings` somewhere. Or maybe my approach is incorrect.

This is my `TestOne` Class

```
public class TestOne extends ActualFragmetIntro {

 @Override
 public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    addSlide(FragmentTest.newInstance("This is the string from TestOne", new String[]{"Button1 Text, Button2 Text ,Button3 text , Button4 Text"}));
```

Below is my FragmentTest fragment

```
public class FragmentTest extends Fragment { 
 private static final String ARG_TITLE = "title";
 private static final String[] ARG_BUTTON_TEXTS_STRINGS = {"buttons_texts"};
 //private static final String ARG_BUTTON_TEXTS_STRINGS = {"buttons_texts"};
 //private static final ArrayList<String> ARG_BUTTON_TEXTS_STRINGS = new ArrayList<String>();

public static FragmentTest newInstance(String title, String[] buttonStrings) {
  FragmentTest sampleSlide = new FragmentTest();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
  args.putStringArrayList(buttonStrings.toString(), ARG_BUTTON_TEXTS_STRINGS);
  sampleSlide.setArguments(args);

  return sampleSlide;
}

public static FragmentTest newInstance(String title, String[] buttonStrings) {
  FragmentTest sampleSlide = new FragmentTest();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
  args.putStringArrayList(buttonStrings.toString(), ARG_BUTTON_TEXTS_STRINGS);
  sampleSlide.setArguments(args);

  return sampleSlide;
}

private String[] getArgButtonTextsStrings = new String[0];

public FragmentTest() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ....
if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().size() != 0) {
  title = getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE);
  getArgButtonTextsStrings = getArguments().getStringArray(String.format(String.valueOf(ARG_BUTTON_TEXTS_STRINGS)));

  System.out.println("logged onCreate " + title +"  "+ getArgButtonTextsStrings );
 }
}
...

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
 super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
  if(isVisibleToUser&& isResumed()){
  title = getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE);
  getArgButtonTextsStrings = getArguments().getStringArray(String.format(String.valueOf(ARG_BUTTON_TEXTS_STRINGS)));

}else {

}
}
```

**EDIT** Added `addSlide` code

```
public abstract class ActualFragmetIntro extends FragmentActivity implements SceneIntroFragment4Objects.ClickCounterListener, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
private PagerIntroAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager pager;
private List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
...

public void addSlide(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
    fragments.add(fragment);
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the data using tag: `buttonStrings.toString()`.
But you are trying to get the data using: `String.format(String.valueOf(ARG_BUTTON_TEXTS_STRINGS))`.

Those tags are different and that's why you are getting a null array.

You should define the tag as a constant:

```
private static final String ARG_BUTTONS_TEXT = "buttons";
```

Then in your newInstance:

```
public static FragmentTest newInstance(String title, String[] buttonStrings) {
    FragmentTest sampleSlide = new FragmentTest();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
    args.putStringArray(ARG_BUTTONS_TEXT, buttonStrings);
    sampleSlide.setArguments(args);

    return sampleSlide;
}
```

And in your onCreate:

```
getArgButtonTextsStrings = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_BUTTONS_TEXT);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. If I do `args.putStringArrayList(ARG_BUTTONS_TEXT, buttonStrings);` I get an error on buttonStrings, saying second parameter is wrong, it found `java.lang.String[]` and it requires `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>`. So I changed the `args.putStringArrayList` to `args.putStringArray`, but that still returns a null value. Should I do `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("one, two ,three , four"))` instead of `new String[]{"one, two ,three , four"}  in `TestOne` class

Comment: Could you post the code in `addSlide` ? Probably you are not using the same Fragment instance

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I added the `addslide` code to my question

Comment: Ahh, your answer was correct. I was making two silly errors.
I changed this
`private String[] getArgButtonTextsStrings = new String[0];`
to
`private String[] getArgButtonTextsStrings;`
and for log `System.out.println("onCreate " +"  "+ Arrays.toString(getArgButtonTextsStrings));`
Thank you very much for your help!!